# PHP - Count number of times string appears in file

Tags: php, file

I've got a file (leaderboard.txt) that looks like this:

```
funkystudios
funkystudios
funkystudios
gilletteracer74
axehairgel
Ferby123
dirdam
TheWu13
Expert_Assassin
TheWu13
ocanosoup
```

I want to be able to read this file, and print out the number of times each person appears in the file. (Also place in order of # of times in file)

```
funkystudios: 3
TheWu13: 2
gilletteracer74: 1
axehairgel: 1
(and so on)
```

I've tried various ways but It all came down to an issue when I would try to order them correctly... I'm guessing there is a pretty easy way to do this. (I'm new to PHP...)

**EDIT:**
I have gotten to this point:

```
  foreach(array_count_values(file('leaderboard.txt')) as $person => $count)
echo "{$person} : {$count}<br />\r\n";
```

It doesn't order by the $count, but simply who comes up first in the file.

Comment: Have you tried `array_count_values(file($filename))`?

Comment: Yes I have tried array count values, check the comment for the first answer to see my real issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$counted = array_count_values(file('leaderboard.txt'));

arsort($counted);

  foreach($counted as $person => $count)
        echo "{$person} : {$count}<br />\r\n";
```

Comment: Ok, I've gotten there, but what I really need to do is order by number of time each user shows up... Right now it is in order of what appears in the file.

Comment: Beat me to it. However expanding on your answer and sorting using the arsort function is simpler: foreach(array_count_values(file('file.txt')) as $person => $count){
    $counts[$person] = $count;
  }
  arsort($counts);
  print_r($counts);

Comment: yes you right, bu don't forget use array_reverse after asort.

Comment: @TufanBarışYıldırım arsort is the reverse of asort. Great answer. Your implementation was  few lines shorter than mine. +1

Comment: Tufan, your solution provided the number of the item in the array rather than the name of the user. (http://pastebin.com/DWFr6RCj), EmmanuelG's solution seemed to work fine! Thanks to you all!