# Counting the number of times a variable has been output to a text file

Tags: php

I have recently been learning to use PHP to create simple web forms which then can be output to a text file at an external location.

The data from the filled out form is filled out in this fashion:

```
$data = "$FirstName | $LastName | $Var1 | $Var2 | $Var3 | \n";
$file = fopen("text.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $data);

fclose($fh);
```

This works just fine - however I am now trying to create an output wherein I can check the number of times the variables $Var1/2/3 have been selected (these are represented as checkboxes within the form - they either are blank (looking like `| |` in the file ) or have the name of the variable assigned within it (e.g. `| Blue Car |`)

How would I go about outputting the number of times the variable "Blue Car" is present within the text file, and echo/print it to a webpage?

An example of what the file looks like currently would be:

```
Jon | Snow | Blue Car | | |
Ben | Dover | | Red Car | Green Car |
Tom | Riddle | Blue Car | | Green Car |
Cave | Johnson | Blue Car | Red Car | |
Rebecca | White |  | Red Car | |
```

Pages I have looked at before requesting the response to this question:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659490/php-count-number-of-times-string-appears-in-file) has a general idea but is single-variable rather than present within a string of "| |"s.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327218/access-a-variable-using-a-counter-as-part-of-the-variable-name) utilises arrays rather than data being pulled from a text file in my case.
- I had also looked [here](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/reading-lines-from-text-file-and-storing-in-php-variable.87591/#post-926596) and understood some of the code written (explode, use of the "for" statement) but I do not know if this can be utilized to solve my problem.

*I am a beginner to php coding, if possible please explain what the code you have responded with does/how it works. **Many thanks.***

Comment: Show what have you tried. Check the PHP function [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php). The list of [PHP functions for string handling](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) used to be (and it still is) a good source of inspiration for me when I started coding in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get number of times your variable is displayed in the text file using this:

```
//read the contents of file as a String
$data = file_get_contents("text.txt") or exit("Could not open file");

//match the word "Blue Car"
preg_match_all("/Blue Car/",$data,$result);

//prints 3 for your example
echo count($result[0]);
```